# Reactjs redux-form getting a "handleSubmit is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have a list of clients page in a React Redux application.

It has three main components - SearchClients at the top, TableHeader in the middle and Clients to render the client list.

My intention is to be able to click on the each header name and sort via that column. Once the column is the one the list is sorted on a sort glyphicon will display either up or down symbol which you should also be able to click on.

I have split off a section of the "TableHeader" component into its own component.

It was working fine until I decided to add a subcomponent to the TableHeader component.

In the console I get the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null

Here is the GlyphiconDirectionChange component that sits in the TableHeader component:

```
const GlyphiconDirectionChange = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props

  const { sortDirection } = props

  return (
    <span>
      {sortDirection === 'Descending' ?
        <span
          style={textLinkStyle}
          onClick={handleSubmit(values =>
            props.onSubmit({
              ...values,
              sortDirection: 'Ascending'
            }
            ))}
          className='glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes'>
        </span>
        :
        <span
          style={textLinkStyle}
          onClick={handleSubmit(values =>
            props.onSubmit({
              ...values,
              sortDirection: 'Descending'
            }
            ))}
          className='glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt'>
        </span>
      }
    </span>
  )}
```

and here is where I add it to the TableHeader component:

```
export const TableHeaders = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props

  const { sortBy, sortDirection } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-2" style={headingCellStyle}>
          <span
            style={textLinkStyle}
            onClick={handleSubmit(values =>
              props.onSubmit({
                ...values,
                sortBy: 'ClientNumber'
              }
              ))}>
            <span>Client # </span>
          </span>

          <GlyphiconDirectionChange sortDirection={sortDirection}/>

        </div>
        <div className="col-md-5" style={headingCellStyle}>
          <span>Name</span>
          {sortBy === 'LastName' && <span>
            {
              sortDirection === 'Descending' ?
                <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes'></span>
                :
                <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt'></span>
            }
          </span>
          }
          <span> / Address </span>
          {sortBy === 'Suburb' && <span>
            {
              sortDirection === 'Descending' ?
                <span>
                  <span> - (sorted by Suburb) </span>
                  <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes'></span>
                </span>
                :
                <span>
                  <span> - (sorted by Suburb) </span>
                  <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt'></span>
                </span>
            }
          </span>
          }

          {console.log(`SortBy ${sortBy} Sort Direction ${sortDirection}`)}
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-2" style={headingCellStyle}>Phone</div>
        <div className="col-md-1" style={headingCellStyle}>Jobs</div>
        <div className="col-md-2" style={headingCellStyle}>Actions</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
TableHeaders.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

const TableHeadersForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'TableHeaders',
})(TableHeaders)

export default TableHeadersForm
```

TableHeader component as, mentioned before, is the second component of the three components. As part of the clients container it has the following logic:

```
changeHeaders = (values = {}) => {
const { query, sortBy, sortDirection } = this.props
values.query = values.query || ''
const searchParams = {
  query,
  sortBy,
  sortDirection,
  ...values,
  currentPage: 1,
}
console.log('changeHeaders()!', values, searchParams)
this.fetchClients(searchParams)
```

}

```
handlePageChanged = (pageIndex) => {
this.fetchClients({
  currentPage: pageIndex,
})
```

}

I am using

```
          onClick={handleSubmit(values =>
          props.onSubmit({
            ...values,
            sortBy: 'ClientNumber'
          }
```

To handle the mouse click and then passing values via props and onSubmit. I believe I have not written this or it could be that its not being handled correctly in the TableHeader component and therefore in the Client container where my logic is....

How should an onClick event be propigated up through component tree in my case?

What have I missed that it is giving me that error and what does that error mean - its not overly descriptive.

Comment: It depends on what `handleSubmit` does in this case (i.e. does it return another function?). It seems like you are trying to pass a function as a prop, like `onClick={() => handleSubmit(values => /*...*/)}` rather than calling it during render

Comment: What I wanted is to take to newly set values for sortDirection in GlyphiconDirectionChange and in the parent clientContainer, be used by the changedHeaders function above.. not sure how to do that correctly in this instance.

Comment: `GlyphiconDirectionChange` expects `handleSubmit` in `props` but you did not pass this to the component